# Revision of a document. Number of pages in a document

Tags: grammar, articles

Let's say I need to list some properties of something, for example, of a document:

> 5: Revision of **a document**.
>
> 1000: Number of pages in **a document**.
>
> [other properties] of **a document**.
>
> ...

Generally, the first time I mention the document I need to use "a" article. The next time I need to use "the" article.

But in this case it seem to me that I need to use "a" article in each element in the list.

Could you please confirm that we should use only "a" article here? Could you please give a brief explanation also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds unnatural to refer to "a document" unless you say that once to introduce it. After that it is a particular document and you should use **the** definite article.

If the sentences are part of the document itself, you can omit that entirely, leaving something like these statistics

> Revision: 5
>   Pages: 1000
>   Tables: 42

Comment: Thank you! Let's say there's a form that should be filled in. The fields of that form must be described somehow, right? Maybe it could mention a document before the fields, but  it is not always the case. What article should we use with "document" when describing the fields of a form?

Comment: Well, take "revisions of a document". **Which** document ? Any document? As I wrote, it is unnatural when you are talking about a specific document. You would use "a document" when taking about documents generally, for example "how many paragraphs must a document have" but even then, it's a strange requirement of a "document" which is a very general term. So my answer is: don't use the indefinite article here.